# make XSD using PHP, WSDL, php array

Tags: php, soap, xsd, wsdl

can somebody help me with: 
How to generate XSD file using PHP, soap client, WSDL definition file, and filled by PHP array???

SOAP client code:

```
$soap = new SoapClient(
URL,
array(
  'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
  'cache_wsdl'   => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
  "style"        => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
  "use"          => SOAP_LITERAL
)
); // init soap server

$soap_response = $soap->__soapCall("someMethodFrom WSD", array($params));
```

But it is possible to make export XSD without submiting data to SOAP server?

A lot of thanx.